# ExpandableListView Swapping issue

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-edittext

I have a problem.

In my ExpandableListView, I have 2 edit text boxes. When I paste text in one of the edittext box, it gets swapped.

Why so..??

Thanks in advance.

The below class is the subclass of main activity. And str is declared in the Activity class. On touching the one editText child, its getting pasted to another edit text child, not the one which is clicked.

```
class ExAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    int width;
    int j=0;
    EditText editFName;
    String str_fname="";
    String str_lname="";

    final String arrGroupelements[] = 
    {
        "Name",
        "PhoneNo",

    };

    final String arrChildelements[][] = 
    {
       {
          "FirstName",
          "LastName"
       },
       {
          "Mobile",
          "Work",
          "Home"       

       }
    };

    final String arrChildhintelements[][] = 
     {
           {
              "FirstName",
              "LastName"
           },
           {
              "Mobile",
              "Work",
              "Home"
           }

     };

    public ExAdapter(Context context, int width) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_child, null);

        }

        TextView txtFName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFname);
        txtFName.setText(arrChildhintelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);


        editFName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editFName);
        editFName.setHint(arrChildhintelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);

        editFName.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                editFName.setText(str); 
                return true;
            }

        });

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please paste your code, that way we can findout the reason, otherwise it would be stab in dark.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I think you need to refer to your editText view dynamically in the onTouch event. Again this is a guess, but I think it might be possible that the editFName variable is overwritten on each call of getChildView() and replaced with the most current editText. This could explain it because the onTouch events would fire as normal, but they would be referring to whichever EditText was most recently set.

Instead you will want to have the onTouch event refer to its own editText view by using the view passed into the event. Just a theory. Try it and hopefully that works.

```
editFName.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            EditText etTouched = (EditText) v;
            etTouched.setText("SOMETHING"); 
            return true;
        }

    });
```